# Which internal time representation from MySQL is this?

Tags: mysql

This is a snap of my current project MySQL console:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| date_time_local     | delta_kWh | prod_hour |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2014-05-25 05:20:00 |     0.169 |         5 |
| 2014-05-25 06:00:00 |     0.751 |         6 |
| 2014-05-25 07:00:00 |     0.743 |         7 |
| 2014-05-25 08:00:00 |     0.830 |         8 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

MySQL shows the prod hour as a number but in the result recived by the client the corresponding values are:

```
[{"date_time_local":"2014-05-25 05:20:00","delta_kWh":"0.169","prod_hour":504403295704449000},
{"date_time_local":"2014-05-25 06:00:00","delta_kWh":"0.751","prod_hour":576460889742377000},
{"date_time_local":"2014-05-25 07:00:00","delta_kWh":"0.743","prod_hour":648518483780304900},
{"date_time_local":"2014-05-25 08:00:00","delta_kWh":"0.830","prod_hour":720576077818232800}]
```

What is the prod hour returned by the server?
My MySQL query  is:

```
var resQuery = "SELECT concat(date_time_local) AS date_time_local, SUM(delta_kWh) AS delta_kWh,     EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_time_local) AS prod_hour FROM local_solar_consumption WHERE date_time_local BETWEEN '" + jsonRequestObj.startdate + "' AND '" + jsonRequestObj.enddate + "' GROUP BY prod_hour";
```

Edit:
I send the result array with:
    that.resultsToSocket(resQuery, "ownProdCons", plotcase, socket);
    rows.push(plotcase);
                rows.push(plottype);
                socket.emit('got_data', rows);

and stringify the result on the client side:

```
 socket.on('got_data', function (data) {

                em.plotCharts(data);

                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));


              });
```

Comment: mysql's standard date/time format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. it can also deal with unix timestamps (plain integers where 0 = midnight jan 1/1970). your prod_hour value is none of those, but given you're dealing with json, they **MIGHT** be javascript timestamps, which is milliseconds since jan 1/1970.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the JSON output?

Comment: I just did an update :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce the result you are getting ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49ae/3)). Are you sure this is the correct query and there is no other processing on the result?

Comment: No other processing but it's my geuss that MySQL returns the prod hour from the datetime timestamp.

Comment: do you have the code of `resultsToSocket()`?

Comment: It's rows.push(plotcase); rows.push(plottype); socket.emit('got_data', rows); like I posted before.

Comment: @ryokan I would recommend you code a simple script that just executes the query and returns the result set in plain-text to check the query output.  Then start adding functionality (converting to JSON, using the socket, etc.), to try and pin-point the root cause.  It appears to me the problem is not on the database, but rather on the code that emits the response.